# Show that the language is not regular using Myhill-Nerode Theorem

Tags: computer-science, regular-language

I saw that similar questions have been answered on this site, but I've been unable to translate those answers to my problem.

$$L=\{ww^R\mid w \in \{a,b\}^*\}$$

This is what I tried:

BWOC, assume that $L$ is regular. Then by M-N theorem, $L$ has a finite number of equivalence classes. Let $x$ and $y$ be strings, $x \neq y$, such that $[x]=[y]$.

This is where I get stuck. What would be the next step in tackling this? Is there a way to do this without contradicting it?

Comment: Note the use of \mid and \in in my edit.  Both of those provide the conventional amount of spacing to their left and right, so I deleted your manually added spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the set of strings $\{a^nb : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$; that is, the set $\{ab, aab, aaab, \ldots\}$.  Can you show that no two strings in this set can be in the same equivalence class?

Comment: What if I start by saying $S_m=a^mb,\mid m\in\mathbb{N}, m \neq n$?

Comment: @blutuu I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You've only swapped a variable in the definition of the strings; you aren't _saying_ anything there.  I'll try and reword my answer to make it slightly more clear what I mean.

Comment: Hmm.Based on you updated answer, I'd say that in order to show no 2 strings can be in the same equivalence class, then $S_m=a^nb^m \mid m \in \mathbb{N}, m\neq n \; and \;m \gt 0$. That seems like a way to move forward. Thoughts?

Comment: Would saying that $a^n$ is infinite show that L is not regular?